# how to connect to servers in MS SQL Server Management Studio using windows credential in SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-connection, windows-authentication

I have multiple servers in my workspace I am trying to connect to and would like to make a single SQL script to do so. To connect to each server Windows Credentials are required and the option on the server is not set otherwise, nor do I have access to them lest I can convince of need.

Is it then possible to use the :Connect command to pass my windows credentials or can I only do so using SQL Server Authentication?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use '-E' for integrated authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `sqlcmd` will use integrated authentication (Windows credentials). You can specify it using `-E`, as dsolimano mentioned, but it's unecessary.

By excluding the `-U` for username and `-P` for password switches, it's implied you wish to use your Windows credentials.

An example would be:

`sqlcmd -S ServerName -i script.sql -o results.txt`

Comment: Thanks, I was having a hard time seeing where this was explicitly called out since I was working within the query editor and am still learning how to properly call options in there.